# Cannot pull golang image in CloudBuild

Tags: go, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I've created a simple go server and am following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/go/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine#use-cloud-build-to-build-the-app) to deploy the server on GCE. But I am getting the following error on my build. What am I missing? I've also tried using a specific version number (i.e. "1.16"), but still fails with a similar error message.

```
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: mirror.gcr.io/library/golang
Step #0: Using default tag: latest
Step #0: Error response from daemon: manifest for mirror.gcr.io/library/golang:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest" from request "/v2/library/golang/manifests/latest".
...
Step #0: Error response from daemon: manifest for mirror.gcr.io/library/golang:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest" from request "/v2/library/golang/manifests/latest".
ERROR: failed to pull because we ran out of retries.
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "mirror.gcr.io/library/golang" failed: error pulling build step 0 "mirror.gcr.io/library/golang": generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (10 attempts): step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the `golang` image isn't available at the moment via this registry. It could be an intermittent issue ‍♂️

```
$ docker pull mirror.gcr.io/library/golang
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for mirror.gcr.io/library/golang:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest" from request "/v2/library/golang/manifests/latest".

// But weirdly this works
gcloud container images list --repository=mirror.gcr.io/library
// And this
docker pull mirror.gcr.io/library/alpine
```

**So I would swap that line with the Golang Docker Hub image in your yaml file.**

```yaml
## Where it says:
- name: 'mirror.gcr.io/library/golang'
## Change to
- name: 'registry.hub.docker.com/library/golang'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the alternative solution! Is `registry.hub.docker.com/library/golang` good replacement to be used in production?

Comment: I would think so, it's the Docker official image for go. Also, this image only builds the go binary. it's not the one that actually runs it on the server.

Comment: Note that  if you are using this in a CI system, you will need a docker hub login (like a site or CI robot license) to prevent rate limits.